How can I add a new UUID column to an existing Snowflake Database and backfill it?
I have an existing database with several million rows and I need to add a non personally identifying unique ID column to it for public accessible views.
I want to use an auto generated UUID and have it backfill, but I am having some problems with the correct syntax.
This is what I have tried in a few iterations which just generate syntax errors:
ALTER TABLE T ADD COLUMN UniqueID varchar(36) DEFAULT UUID_STRING() NOT NULL;

you can’t create a not null column on a table that already contains rows, as each row would violate the not null at the point you add the column. Instead you need to:

Add the column as nullable
Populate it for every row
Alter the column to make it not null


That's not true. You can add a not null column with a default value just fine because Snowflake then assigns the default value to all existing rows.

"it does not assign it" as a write operation, it assigns as a read opperation. If the column is not being "read" because noby is referening to a non-existance column from the future (and nobody is doing select *) the column will not have be evaluated.

@SimeonPilgrim That's interesting, do you have a link to the documentation for this?

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table#table-column-actions-tablecolumnaction. The defualt has to be a constant, because it is stored on the table as read throw value. Not written the the actual table. To do this you should manually rewrite the table.

Somehwat surprisingly, this apparently is not possible. You can add a new column with NOT NULL and DEFAULT value, but it seems Snowflake does not support procedure calls in this case.
This works:
create table t (
  pk number,
  UniqueID varchar(36) DEFAULT UUID_STRING() NOT NULL
);

insert into t(pk) values(1);

and this works, as well:
create table t (pk number);
insert into t(pk) values(1);
ALTER TABLE T ADD COLUMN UniqueID varchar(36) DEFAULT 'x' NOT NULL;

but this doesn't work:
create table t (pk number);
insert into t(pk) values(1);
ALTER TABLE T ADD COLUMN UniqueID varchar(36) DEFAULT UUID_STRING() NOT NULL;

and neither does this:
create table t (pk number);
insert into t(pk) values(1);
ALTER TABLE T ADD COLUMN UniqueID varchar(36) DEFAULT 'x' NOT NULL;
alter table t modify column uniqueID default uuid_string();

Both variants raise an error - either "Unsupported feature 'Alter Column Set Default'" or Invalid column default expression [UUID_STRING()]
To me, this seems like a bug - the Snowflake documentation explicitly mentions restrictions on sequences with SET DEFAULT, but nothing regarding stored procedure calls.
The only workaround I can think of would be to

create a new_table with the correct default behaviour
copy the data from the old_table
rename the old_table to old_table_bak
rename the new_table to old_table
drop the old_table

but before going that way, you might want to contact Snowflake support.
UPDATE The Snowflake documentation for ALTER TABLE explicitly mentions that adding non-literal default values is not possible:

A default value for a column that you are adding must be a literal
value; it cannot be an expression or a value returned by a function.
... When you first create a table, you can use expressions as default
values, but not when you add columns.


I don't believe this is a bug.  The issue is that you can't use a function like uuid_string() as a default value.  According to the documentation, a DEFAULT value must be a constant, a sequence, or a simple expression that returns a scalar value.  I don't think a UUID is a scalar function.

That's not correct. You can use uuid_string() as a default value just fine if you put it into the CREATE TABLE statement. See the first part of my answer.

I missed that.  Thanks for pointing it out.  I wasn't sure whether it was considered a scalar value function or not.

Your last attempt above should fail according to the documentation, as it does say that altering a default value is not supported.  So, that seems consistent with the docs.  It's the first failing statement that seems off.

@MikeWalton I did some more doc digging, and it explicitly mentions that adding columns with non-literal default values is not possible. See my updated answer.
